# Why it says "Calls to launch should happen inside a LaunchedEffect and not composition"?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am new in jetpack compose , I try to build small project to learn jetpack compose, I have example code , and for

```
composableScope.launch
```

it throw an error as a Calls to launch should happen inside a LaunchedEffect and not composition for `launch`, any idea?

```
 val composableScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val currentPage = onBoardViewModel.currentPage.collectAsState()

Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState
    ) {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            composableScope.launch {
                pagerState.animateScrollToPage(
                    page = currentPage.value
                )
            }
}
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't directly call a coroutine in a "composition" (the place in your Composable function where you're declaring your UI) because this function can be called any time and several times by the Compose framework.

Instead, you should use `LaunchedEffect` if you want to call a coroutine during a composition (read more [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect)). Or if you need a coroutine in an event (like a click) you should use the `rememberCoroutineScope`.

```
LaunchedEffect(someKey) { // the key define when the block is relaunched
    // Your coroutine code here
}
```

or

```
Modifier.clickable {
    coroutineScope {
        // your coroutine here
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile with `Modifier.clickable`